# Horizontal navigation make current li taller

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a horizontal navigation where the list items need to span the entire width **and** the 'active' list item needs to be taller than the rest of the items.

Was successful in getting the list items to span the entire width by setting the ul to display: table and the list items to display: table-cell.

```
#l-primary-nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
}

#l-primary-nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

What I'm unable to figure out is how to make the 'active' list item a bit taller than the rest. Thought I would set a margin-top: 5px to the #l-primary-nav li (above) and remove the margin-top from the active li (below), however table-cell items do not accept margins.

```
#l-primary-nav li.active {
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-right: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
}
```

Here's a link to the navigation bar so far: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/melcsweeney/55jkv/)

I would like the 'About' navigation item to be about 5 pixels taller than the rest. Hope to use a CSS only solution. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/webdevkumar/55jkv/1/

Answer (score 2):

Please do refer to the following fiddler: **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevkumar/55jkv/1)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="l-primary-nav">
<ul class="l-inline">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Calendar</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
l-primary-nav {
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto; 
}
.l-inline li {
display: inline-block;
}
l-primary-nav ul {
width: 99.8%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
float: left;
display: table;
}
l-primary-nav li {
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
float: left;
}
l-primary-nav li a{
line-height: 40px;
height: 41px;
padding: 0 30px;
border-top: 1px transparent;
display: block;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.18, #FBFBFB), color-stop(1, #D1D1D1));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #D1D1D1 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #D1D1D1 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #D1D1D1 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #D1D1D1 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #D1D1D1 100%);
}
l-primary-nav li a:hover {
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #E1E3E6), color-stop(1, #BABCBF));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E1E3E6 0%, #BABCBF 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E1E3E6 0%, #BABCBF 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E1E3E6 0%, #BABCBF 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E1E3E6 0%, #BABCBF 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E1E3E6 0%, #BABCBF 100%);
}

l-primary-nav li.active a{
margin-top: -5px;
height: 45px;
position: relative;
background: #fff;
border-left: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-right: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-top: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
}
```

Comment: This solution does not allow the list items to automatically span the full width. Looks like adding the float:left to the #l-primary-nav li takes the full span away. Is there a way to allow for a full width span and have different heights?

Comment: Using your solution as a base I was able to keep the list items expanding to the full width while giving the active list item a taller height. Here's a link to the final code: http://jsfiddle.net/melcsweeney/xc5Y2/

Answer (score 2):

This may help you

```
 #l-primary-nav li {
     display:block;
     width:140px;
     float:left;
     text-align: center;
     margin-top:4px;
     border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
 }
```

I have given display:block for li element and added width :

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/ggbhat/af82E/1/

Comment: This solution also takes away the list items spanning the full width automatically. I need to avoid giving the list items a set width.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of the proposed solutions above I was able to keep the list items spanning the full width while giving the active list item a taller height. Link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/melcsweeney/xc5Y2/

```
#l-primary-nav {
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.l-inline li {
display: inline-block;
}
#l-primary-nav ul {
width: 99.8%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-left: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-right: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
float: left;
display: table;
}
#l-primary-nav li {
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
border-top: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
}

#l-primary-nav li a{
line-height: 40px;
height: 41px;
border-top: 1px transparent;
display: block;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.18, #FBFBFB), color-stop(1, #D1D1D1));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #D1D1D1 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #D1D1D1 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #D1D1D1 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #D1D1D1 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #D1D1D1 100%);
}
#l-primary-nav li a:hover {
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #E1E3E6), color-stop(1, #BABCBF));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E1E3E6 0%, #BABCBF 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E1E3E6 0%, #BABCBF 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E1E3E6 0%, #BABCBF 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E1E3E6 0%, #BABCBF 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E1E3E6 0%, #BABCBF 100%);
}

#l-primary-nav li.active a{
margin-top: -5px;
height: 45px;
position: relative;
background: #fff;
border-left: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-right: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
border-top: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
}
```